# Laravel automaticly redirect on authentication exception

Tags: php, laravel

im working with laravel 5.5 and tried to protect an api route. I assigned the 'auth' middleware to this route, but when i tested it, i get an InvalidArgumentException aka 'Route [login] is not defined'. Im not reffering to this route in any way, laravel automaticaly tried to redirect to this route. I found the following code line in file 'laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php':

```
/*
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

So im wondering, whats the best way to catch this exception globally on every route?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, its because you added an `auth` middleware to the route. So whenever the route is accessed without an authentication, the route is redirected to the `name login route` which is the login page by default.

You can add an `unauthenticated` method to your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` with the following code. So if the request is in `API` or expecting `JSON` response, it will give a `401` status code with JSON response. If the route is accessed using web routes, it will be redirected to the default page. In the below example, am redirecting it to a login page.

Note: This method existed in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` till laravel 5.4.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    return redirect()->guest(('login'));
}
```

Don't forget to import `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;`

Edit: Explanation for the error `Route [login] is not defined`. This is because laravel is trying to redirect to a `named route`. This named route is available if you are using the `laravel auth scaffolding`. If you are manually creating the functions, even if the route `login` exists, it should be named as `login`. For more information, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes